# How to set placeholder image for Image getting loaded from service?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I'm using binding for source of an Image control.

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImageUri}"/>
```

But my image source getting an image from service, so its take time to load the image, in meanwhile I would like to show my placeholder image. How to do this in Winrt application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is there any other third party controls supports automatically for placeholder image.

Answer (score 1):

I dono the exact solution. But u can do it by this work around.

placing image into grid, that grid having background as your default image.

```
<Grid Width="104" Height="104" >
<Grid.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/DefaultImage.png"/>
</Grid.Background>
<Image Source="{Binding ImgSrc,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Stretch="Uniform" />
```

Comment: Have you suggest any other third party controls for this

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**
Also, you can use ImageFailed Event for the Image Control.
You can achieve this using Behaviours in XAML for a hassle free solution.

**Method 2:** 
You can also use Binding.TargetNullValue to Achieve your requirment.

```
<Image>
    <Image.Source>
        <Binding Path="ImagePath" >
            <Binding.TargetNullValue>
                <ImageSource>/Assets/DefaultImage.png</ImageSource>
            </Binding.TargetNullValue>
        </Binding>
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

Comment: this is working when image source is as null, its not working while image loading time

Answer (score 0):

For UWP, there is [ImageEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/controls/imageex) control (in [Windows Community Toolkit](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsCommunityToolkit)).

```
<controls:ImageEx Name="ImageExControl" IsCacheEnabled="True"
  PlaceholderSource="/assets/thumbnails/thumbnails.png"
   Source="/assets/bigPicture.png"/>
```